# Why won’t Bool Tool create a hole?

Tags: modifiers

I have been using Bool Tool lately with success, however occasionally I run into a situation where it refuses to do what I want. Here I'm trying to create a square hole in the larger beveled cube, but no matter which Bool Tool operation I apply, or order of selected objects, I cannot get a hole. What am I doing wrong? Thanks. Blender 3.01, Windows 11

Note I converted the larger beveled cube to mesh thinking that would help, but no joy.
[Blend file](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/Why_wont_Bool_Tool_create_a_hole.blend)

[image]

Comment: It looks like one face normal is inverted ? Try SHIFT N in edit mode

Comment: The normals are ok. It's just not manifold. The *Boolean* modifier works fine but the *Bool Tool* does strange things with this object. The *Union* and *Difference* operations do the opposite... ?

Comment: @Blunder I forgot about the Boolean modifier; I'm such a modelling noob. Using the modifier, I got it to work by selecting the small cube as the Object and choosing Union.